# Image.Tag is null when added to ImageList in C#

Tags: c#, image

I have the following code which reads a image from a Url and adds the image to a ImageList.

```
WebClient oWebClient = new WebClient();
Uri oUri = new Uri("http://www.mysite.com/images/image1.jpg");

try
{
    Image oImage = Image.FromStream(oWebClient.OpenRead(oUri));
    oImage.Tag = "hello World";
    imageList1.Images.Add("test", oImage);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("Error getting photo: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Everything works fine, except for some reason the Image tag is empty when I inspect it in the imageList1 object ?  Why is this happening ?

Comment: Are you sure you're inspecting `Image.Tag` and not `ImageList.Tag`?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking at Image.Tag, for the only image I have in my ImageList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would steer away from using the `Tag` property on objects, as it can be unreliable (as you see) as well as not being very extensible.

In your case `ImageList.Add(key, image)` uses the `key` parameter is so you can retrieve that `Image` later using `ImageList[key]` indexer property.

If you are trying to store more data into the `Tag` property, I would recommend you instead create your own data model class and use that instead.

It is much easier to keep a `List<T>` or `Dictionary<Key, Value>` of your type for retrieval instead of playing with `Tag` casting/lookup.

Comment: Even trying to add imageList1.Images.Add(oImage), the tag is null.  The reason I'm using the tag, is because ideally I want to pass a object within the Image, that is passed to and added to the ImageList.

Comment: Whichever `key` you are passing to `Images.Add(key, oImage)`, you should use that same `key` to store your object to a separate `Dictionary<string, T>` so you can map `key->object` for the images. I am recommending you avoid the `Tag` property all together.

Comment: I just came across a forum post on msdn stating "You cannot use the Image.Tag property because upon adding the image to the ImageList this property will get stripped out."